# How to show multiple columns from objects in a datagridview using BindingSource?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an object that I would like to show in a datagridview. The object (a movement) has a name, a weight and then some Location objects. The Locations each have a name and a value. What I want to be able to do is for each movement to show the name, weight, location1.name, location1.value, location2.name, location2.value each in their own column of the DGV.

I've managed to override the toString method for Location but that only gives me 1 column per Location, I really want to be able to have two. Is there any way to do this? I'm currently using a BindingSource like this

```
BindingSource movementSource = new BindingSource();

movementsSource.DataSource = aircraft.movements;

MovementDataGridView.DataSource = movementsSource;
```

If it makes any difference movements is a `List<Movement>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is create a wrapper class like this:

```
class MovementView {
   private Movement movement;
   public MovementView(Movement m) { movement = m; }

   public string Name { get { return movement.Name; } }
   // etc..
   public string Location1Name { get { return movement.Locations[0].Name; } }
   // etc..
}
```

Then bind the grid to a `List<MovementView>` instead:

```
movementsSource.DataSource = aircraft.movements
    .Select(t => new MovementView(t))
    .ToList();
```